# Fastest data structure for inserting data, not for searching

Tags: c++, data-structures

Can anyone please tell me which is the fastest data structure for inserting data. My requirements are to load names of people, and then retrieve them at super fast speed. There is no question of sorting, searching a specific name etc, not even memory, because total people may not be more than 20. The single requirement is load people and retrieve the names at a later stage.
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Hash table should fit the bill. Anything more than that seems like overkill.

Comment: Since you know the upper limit, static arrays looks like a good choice to me. @squiguy- Why hashtables? He's not searching with names as key.

Comment: Retrieve the names in... -The same order? -Any order is ok? -Specific names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the tongue in check answer (it was my first thought) and you have at most 20 people, just use an array.

Comment: Thanks all of you. I think arrays will be my answer. I'm wondering how you people respond to questions instantly, the moment I posted the question, you replied to it. That's amazing!!!

Answer (score 10):

Tongue-in-cheek answer: if you are **only** doing insertions and nothing else, the easiest data structure is nothing at all - just don't store anything.  That makes insertions instantaneous, since you do absolutely nothing to do an insertion.

More realistic answer: if you are just trying to store a bunch of data as quickly as possible and you have an upper bound on the number of total elements, just use an array and keep track of the next free index.  If the array stores pointers to elements, then each insertion is a pointer assignment plus an increment of the next free index.  If you're storing copies, then each insertion makes a copy (which you'd have to do anyway) and an increment.  Since *any* structure that stores elements has to either store a pointer or copy to it, the overhead is a single increment, which I'm fairly confident is about as cheap as it gets.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that total objects / nodes will always be less than 20 than array is the best. Retreival happens using index in array and is the fastest.
If you are not sure of the size of datastructure, then I will suggest a list because insertion in a list is the fastest provided you are not looking for an order of insertion. If order of insertion is needed then go for linked list.
Hashtable might not be an option because it has an extra overhead of synchronozation which is not needed here.
A Set interface could be used if you want to avoid duplicates and you have no worries about the order of retrieval.